# Read Access Violation C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The below code compiles. But when I execute in debugging mode, I get read access violation in the location marked by comment below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct information
{
    int32_t bytes;
    std::string packet_header;
};

class updateClassList
{

public:

    std::vector<information*> vecptr;

   void updateClassListN()
    {
        cout << "inside constructor";
        for (int32_t i = 0;i < 2;i++)
        {
            information* ptr = new information();

            ptr->bytes = i;
            ptr->packet_header = "Heavy";

            vecptr.push_back(ptr); // READ ACCESS VIOLATION
            
        }
    }//endctr

};

class updateClass
{
public:
    int32_t bytes;
    std::string packet_header;
    updateClass** item;
};

updateClass* GetObjectbyHandle(int32_t handle)
{
    updateClass* tmpObj=NULL;
    updateClassList* tmpObjList=NULL;
    tmpObjList->updateClassListN();
    tmpObj->bytes = tmpObjList->vecptr.at(handle)->bytes;
    tmpObj->packet_header = tmpObjList->vecptr.at(handle)->packet_header;
    return tmpObj;
}

bool updater(information* tmpPtr, int32_t handle)
{
    cout << "in updater function";
    updateClass* obj = GetObjectbyHandle(handle);
    if (obj == NULL) return false;
    tmpPtr->bytes = obj->bytes;
    tmpPtr->packet_header = obj->packet_header;
    cout << tmpPtr->packet_header;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int32_t handle = 0;
    information n;
    cout << "in main";
    bool b = updater(&n, handle);
    std::cout << "Decoder Status: " << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Follow up question:

Calling the `updater(&n, handle);` multiple times with `handle` alternating between `0,1` leads to increased memory usage.

1. Should local pointer class variables with pointer members be destructed?
2. If a  function returns references to different objects upon each call, is it a leak if not deleted?

Thanks

Comment: GetObjectbyHandle calls `updateClassListN` on a NULL pointer you assigned a line above. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: This common problem is called "useless use of pointers". About 90% of pointer usage in the shown code does not accomplish anything, and only makes things more complicated and error-prone than it needs to be.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The point of the above program is not to showcase a good code. Rather put forward a template of a code from another project I am handling which depicts a leak.